# Loop over different divs using v-for in vue js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

someone can help me to loop using v-for statement the layout like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfF5f.png)

how can i using v-for in this case ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: there's documentation on `v-for` here that may be helpful: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: @Daniel thank you i already tried https://jsfiddle.net/achmad_maulana_dev/9ek2n5v3/3/

Comment: From the fiddle, it looks like you got it working. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've put a bit much logic into your template, and uses three instances of a loop.

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Product:</h2>
  <div class="row" v-for="(sparator, index) in products" v-if="index % 5 == 0">
    <div class="col col-6" v-for="(product, key) in products" v-if="index <= key && key < (index + 2)">
      <label>{{ product.text }}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-4" v-for="(product, key) in products" v-if="(index + 2) <= key && key < (index + 5)">
      <label>{{ product.text }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could reduce it to two loops, where the class gets computed based on the key

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Product:</h2>
  <div class="row" v-for="(sparator, index) in products" v-if="index % 5 == 0">
    <div class="col" :class="['col-' + ((key % 5 >= 2)?'4':'6')] v-for="(product, key) in products" v-if="index <= key && key < (index + 5)">
      <label>{{ product.text }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but you still have some inefficiency, where you're looping over the entire array multiple times, and because of how they're nested, the computation grows exponentially.

because you are using an array, you could use just the index in your nested loop

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Product:</h2>
  <div class="row" v-for="(sparator, index) in products" v-if="index % 5 == 0">
    <div class="col" :class="['col-' + ((key % 5 >= 2)?'4':'6')]" v-for="(product, key) in 5" v-if="products[index+key]">
      <label>{{ products[index+key].text }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ystxow02/

But still, this is (IMO) a problem, because your template should not be this complicated. The idea is that the template renders the layout, not computes it. So I would use a `computed` to create the data in a way that it's the easiest to use in template.

js:

```
  computed: {
    productLayout() {
        let s = [];
      this.products.forEach((p, i) => {
        let s_index = Math.floor(i / 5) * 2 + ((i % 5 >= 2)? 1 : 0);
        if (s[s_index] === undefined) {
            s[s_index] = {class:"row", products:[]};
        }
        let className = i%5 >= 2 ? 'col-4' : 'col-6';
        s[s_index].products.push({class:className, ...p})
      })
      console.log(s)
      return s;
    }
  }
```

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Product:</h2>
  <div class="row" v-for="(s, i) in productLayout">
    <div class="col" :class="product.class" v-for="(product, k) in s.products">
      <label>{{ product.text }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5pz2urn0/